# Sources- destination matrix from connection matrix

Tags: python, matrix, connection

I have a list of sources and destination vectors like this:

```
sourcelist      =      [1, 2, 3, 4]
destinationlist =      [0, 1, 0, 3]
```

This is from a Directional Graph.One item in the source list will connect to a respective item in the destination list at the same index. Multiple sources can connect to a single destination and vice versa.

From this I create the map like this:

[Network graph, click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMw0E.png)

Now I want to create a matrix showing the dependency between sources and destinations. Such that, the row showing the sources and the column shows the destination. If there is either direct or indirect connection with the sources the value of the respective row and column will be 1.

And this is the matrix I want to have:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Explanation: example, the row 1 shows the connection of node 1. It sources from itself and node 2, so cell[1,1] and cell[1,2] =1. The connection with node 1 on row 1 is not required as the node 0 is the destination of node 1.

I have tried many times but it wasn't sucessful. Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: in your 5x5 matrix there's a 2 where you should only have 1s or is that intentional?  Also how exactly does your destination list work? Never mind the desination list is about which notes are reached from the source list. Though are only 1 directional paths and 1 outgoing path per node allowed?

Comment: Than you for the observation on typo. I have corrected the matrix and add an explanation in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

slist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dlist = [0, 1, 0, 3]
nodes = set(slist + dlist)
slist = np.array(slist)
dlist = np.array(dlist)
matrix = np.eye(len(nodes))
for n in nodes:
    checked = set()
    to_check = np.where(dlist == n)[0]
    while len(to_check) > 0:
        to_check, i = to_check[1:], to_check[0]
        s, d = slist[i], dlist[i]
        if len(checked) == len(slist):
            break
        if s in checked:
            continue
        matrix[n, s] = 1
        checked.add(s)
        to_check = np.append(to_check, np.where(dlist == s)[0])

print(matrix)
```

Under the assumption that each node is only the source of 1 other node this should work. Though there are probably better ways to implement that.